# MacBook Air 13" data access

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Air won’t turn on. The charger is also not working and I don’t have a backup on Time Machine, so is there a way to get the backup if it’s not turning on?

It’s gone for service now but if it comes back with no previous data is there a way to get it back?

Comment: If you don't have a Time Machine backup, how will you 'get the backup'?

Answer (score 1):

In the slightest possible case, if the hard drive remains untouched, you stand a chance of getting all your data intact (OS + user data).

In the current scenario, without a backup, there is no way to access your data from MacBook Air.